# How to add the external user in azure active directory using graph api

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-ad-graph-api

I was try to add the external user in Azure active directory. i was added using dashboard and it's send the invitation link and user accept and set the password using link and users was added in active directory.

[image]

i was add the guest user and send the invitation link and accept link and set password in azure directory. the globe symbol is a added user of external user

[image]

but i was try to add the external user using Rest api in azure active directory.

I was check using Postman

[image]

i was checking in microsoft docs [create invitation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/invitation_post) it given url in beta i was checked in that url and i was try to create the user in ad but the response is

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid version",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "464934b2-8915-418e-8761-87778059692e",
            "date": "2017-09-19T13:30:26"
        }
    }
}
```

i was try to create the tenant id in url but it's return

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'invites'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2d940a4e-4ffe-4a3f-91e8-b94cb3536a59",
            "date": "2017-09-19T13:13:49"
        }
    }
}
```

and i also check in https://www.eliostruyf.com/adding-guests-to-an-office-365-group-via-the-microsoft-graph-api/

it's show response return creation type invitation but i not get expected result.

and i need for add the existing user. with or without invitation in ad. anyone know share the info.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint is https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/invitations :

[image: Invitation - Postman]

When acquiring the *access token*, you should also use a scope like `User.Invite.All` .

More information about the API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/invitation_post

#### EDIT

Use this link for details as the above link is broken:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: which are permission are active in  Application Permissions and Delegated permission for invite user in Azure Active Directory. this is create the user active directory but, not send the invitation link in user Any Link is Avail for Graph API Permission.share the link please, Thanks

Comment: Any of `User.Invite.All`, `User.ReadWrite.All` or `Directory.ReadWrite.All` can be used to allow a user/ app to invite users - knowing that `User.Invite.All` is the most specific. More details [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions)

Comment: Invitations Security Detail - Application Security Setup - You may find this answer useful ...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429059/ms-graph-guid-for-permission-user-invite-all/46447317#46447317

Comment: @AndreTeixeira just a head's up: your link broke so I added the new one. Also, +1 for the answer. First page on Google is literally nothing but "do it in azure portal."